# python log doesn't info message when it is called the second time

Tags: python, logging

in main.py call main_run.run function:

```
print("********* one *********")
main_run.run("conf_rg.ini","rg")

print("********* two *********")
main_run.run("conf_sh.ini","sh")  #info nothing
```

main_run.run function:

```
 def run(conf_path,system):
    # logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(here, "conf_log.ini"))
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("######## info message {0} info message 
    ########".format(system))
    
    logger.info("0.start")
    # get config
    cfg=get_config(conf_path)
    ...
```

the second function call doesn't info message, so why?

Comment: What is *here*? What is the purpose of *conf_path*? What's in conf_log.ini ?

Comment: here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(___file___)), conf_log.ini is for fileConfig use.
conf_path point to the different conf_**.ini.

Comment: but your code doesn't use *conf_path*

Comment: Now I add the code of conf_path, but I think my question have nothing to do with it. The question is about the `logger`

Comment: I find the officer document,it writes:"All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application". But I still don't understand the reason

Answer (score 0):

```
# logging
logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(here, "conf_log.ini"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 
def run(conf_path,system):
    logger.info("######## info message {0} info message 
    ########".format(system))
    
    logger.info("0.start")
    # get config
    cfg=get_config(conf_path)
```

I change the code to this ,it can log info no matter how many times I call.

I still want to know why?